# how to call a function inside variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This probably is a basic question but i am stuck here.

```
const activate = (server, plugin) => {
  let handlers = {
    async beginBlock(request) {
      //...my functon code here
    }
  }
};
```

I want to know how to call `beginBlock()`function from a outside library?
so far I tried `activate.handlers.beginBlock(request)`, which didn't work.

Comment: you could try to `return handlers` and use it as `activate().beginBlock(request)`

Comment: `await handlers.beginBlock(request)`

Comment: i m sorry but i m not authorised to change the code, but `activate`is been exported by `module.exports`. so it still wouldn't be possible to refer without returning `handlers`? @phizi @Adelin

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const activate = (server, plugin) => {
    const beginBlock = async (request) => {
        //...my functon code here
    }
    return beginBlock;
};

const beginBlock = activate(server, plugin);
beginBlock(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to expand on Rahul Sharma's response with slightly updated code that will allow you to have more than one function available for calling from outside your library.

```
const activate = (server, plugin) => {
    const beginBlock = async (request) => {
        //...my functon code here
    }
    const endBlock = async (request) => {
        //... my function code here
    }
    return {
        beginBlock: beginBlock,
        endBlock: endBlock
    };
};

const beginBlock = activate(server, plugin);
beginBlock(request);

const endBlock = activate(server, plugin);
endBlock(request);
```